# Why is the Starfleet insignia drawn tilted to the left in Star Trek: The Animated Series?

Tags: star-trek-tas

In most scenes from Star Trek: The Animated Series, the insignia on the character's uniforms appears drawn tilted about 25 degrees to the audience's left.

This doesn't appear to be a perspective illusion, since it doesn't seem to matter whether the characters are facing left or right.

Was this some sort of mistake or is there an intentional reason for it?

[image: Star Trek: TAS characters facing in multiple directions]

Comment: out of universe, one of the hallmarks of the animation studio was taking shortcuts in production (ex: characters speaking with their hands over their mouth, so you don't have to animate the mouth moving).  I don't know if that is why, thus just a comment, but I wouldn't be surprised lol

Comment: https://www.facttrek.com/blog/emblematic

Comment: ^ that comment should come with a damn warning! - a'la TV Tropes ;) Nice info there @Valorum

Comment: Speaking of TV Tropes, this seems like it might be a mild example of [Unmoving Plaid](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UnmovingPlaid) - a common "cheat" in animation where more complex patterns (like plaid clothes or these insignias) just look the same from every angle. As said above, it fits with the rest of the notoriously cheap animation.